# C# Question DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a data grid and I am data bindding it to an array like this

```
        myDataGrid.DataSource = vals;
        myDataGrid.DataBind();
```

So the first column shows fine, How can I add  a column ON THE RIGHT of buttons?

This is the only thing I have, and it is binded to my array

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="myDataGrid"
BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" 
GridLines="None">
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: This is not nearly enough info.  Need more code or more info about what you are trying to do.  What buttons are you talking about?  Maybe you need to be using a different type for your datasource (i.e. DataTable) if you need multiple columns.

Comment: please post code for the gridview in the aspx or view page

Comment: OK I got the buttons to show with ItemTemplate but how can i make to move to the right of the existing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:DataGrid>
    <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateColumn>
              <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Button />
              </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

That will add a new column of buttons to your datagrid.

Comment: Would this add it on the right of the data being binded to the array?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a DataGrid template and bind individual columns to positions in your array.

This article covers it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301573.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's in your array, if it's one dimensional it will only populate on field
Try to set the AutoGenerateColumns to true

```
 myDataGrid.DataSource = vals;
 myDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns= true
 myDataGrid.DataBind();
```